# ScrollTop Freezing Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this to scroll the page to bottom smoothly:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("html, body").height()}, "slow");
```

But it's freezing my scroll (i'm not able to scroll to top...)

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What browser are you in? jQuery version? Code context? This snippet alone seems to work at least in my browser (firefox 54)

Comment: Jquery 3.2, Chrome.  My code is a form, where user click in field and page scroll to bottom

`$('.select_relacao_com_segurado').on('change', function(e){
  $('.botao_send').show('slow');
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("html, body").height()}, "slow");
 });`

Comment: What if you remove `$('.botao_send').show('slow');`?

Comment: @Piyin, no effect...

Comment: If you could share all the code with us, it would help us see what the error might be. Since the code you shared works, I think it's related to something more